# 5 seconds image intro with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have one mp3 song `song.mp3` and 2 jpg files `1.jpg 2.jpg`
Now, I want to make video from mp3 with jpgs as a background, but in a way so that 1.jpg streams for first 5 seconds then 2.jpg till the rest of the song.

This is not working

```
ffmpeg -i 1.jpg -t 5 -loop_input 2.jpg -i song.mp3 -shortest -acodec copy video.flv
```

I know there is a way to do it when you get length of the song, but prefered way would be without knowing the length, if it exists.